# map() in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

Reduce() is working fine but when I use the same Lambda() with Map() it's showing TypeError.
I'm not able to resolve the error.

```
l = [2,4,6,8,10]
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,l)
```

#### output:

30

```
l = [2,4,6,8,10]
map(lambda x,y: x+y,l)
```

#### output:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 map(lambda x,y: x+y,l)
>
> TypeError: () takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Why would you *expect* to be able to just switch in `map` instead of `reduce` with your reducer and get something reasonable?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of function map? If you provide a lambda of 2 inputs, I can't imagine how to map.

Comment: @liliscent Nothing to do with the question, but you can pass `map` multiple iterables if the function has a higher arity: try e.g. `list(map(min, [1, 2], [3, 1]))`

Answer (score 2):

This is a misunderstanding of what `map` does. It doesn't take two arguments (unlike reduce), rather a function called by a map takes a single argument and returns the list where all arguments are modified using a function. For instance:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> map(lambda arg: arg + 1, a)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here a function increments an argument, so all elements of an array are incremented.

Comment: This not really true, the function should take as many arguments as iterables you pass to the map function